# Noise problems in current sensing

Tags: filter, noise, switching, low-pass, current-sensing

I have the following circuit:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f2nVNh.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

I am using a motor from an electric bike, as a generator and I am rotating it using a drill, to test its regenerative properties. The energy generated is consumed by R1. The current flowing through the circuit is controlled by a low-side N-MOS switch, using the STP55NF06L N-Mosfet. Its gate is driven by a PWM signal (at 500Hz) and an ICL7667 Mosfet driver.

I am using both a multimeter and the [attopilot current sensor 90A version](https://cdn.sparkfun.com/datasheets/Sensors/Current/DC%20Voltage%20and%20Current%20Sense%20PCB%20with%20Analog%20Output.pdf).

The output of the current sensor is driven to an AnalogToDigital port of my microcontroller. The problem is that the current readings I get from the sensor, are not steady and are changing rapidly, while the multimeter shows a nice, steady current value.

I decided to check the output of the current sensor using an osciloscope. With the N-MOSFET duty cycle set to 60%, and a current of around 1A (as measured from the multimeter), these were the results:

This picture has a 1V/div scale:
[image]

This picture has a 500mV/div scale:
[image]

How can I filter the above noisy signal to get a nice current reading from the sensor, like the one of the multimeter, that seems to be the mean value of the current flowing through the circuit?

Comment: Have you considered low-pass filtering the output of the current sensor?

Comment: A drill near an oscilloscope? That's like trying to hear someone whispering near a waterfall. Low pass filtering, as suggested by Swen, is a possible solution. I wonder if there is a way to shield the RFI by operating the drill inside a thick metal box. Also, how did you probe the circuit? Ground spring or dreadful antenna ground loop? A differential pre-amplifier might be helpful too.

Comment: It looks like you may have some inductive component behavior (the generator).  You might try putting a zener diode across the M1 to release energy from any inductive components.

Comment: Unfortunately, I have little experience in filters. I have tried some simple low pass filters, unsuccessfully. Any detailed advice on how to calculate and choose the correct filter for the above case, will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: if you found a solution to this, it's always okay to post an informative answer to your own question in Stack Exchange, and in a day or two to click "accept" as well. This informs future readers that a solution was found and encourages them to click on it and read further.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you are trying to filter the digital value as stored on your microcontroller. I would implement a [moving average](https://www.investopedia.com/university/movingaverage/movingaverages1.asp) on the value. It's easier than filtering the signal through an analog circuit..

[Here](https://gist.github.com/bmccormack/d12f4bf0c96423d03f82) is someone who has implemented a moving average in C. Just remember to keep length of the average short enough.

Comment: If ADC has low enough sampling rate, it won't even see those spike.

Comment: ADC might take the sample DURING the spike.

Comment: I have tried some "software filters", but as mentioned above, the sampling does often occur during a spike.