# DS3231M Current Consumption

Tags: power-supply, current, rtc

I have bought a [DS3231M](https://datasheets.maximintegrated.com/en/ds/DS3231M.pdf) Real time clock. 
From the datasheet, one can see that when the RTC is powered from VCC with 3.63V, the max current I_CCA is 200uA when I2C is active, and I_CCS 130uA when I2C is inactive. These numbers are supposed to include the temperature conversion current, as it says in the datasheet. However, it also mentions a Temperature Conversion Current I_CCSCONV that reaches up to 575uA

When powered from the battery, the max current with Vbat=3.63V is I_BATA 70uA with I2C active, and I_BATT 3uA with I2C inactive. Note 4 also says that it includes the average temperature conversion current.

However one can also find to the battery characteristics a temperature conversion current I_BATC of 575uA maximum.

So, my question is how can I know the average current consumption when powered from VCC and when powered from Vbat? Also, it seems that if I have one power source, it is better to power it only from VBAT.

Comment: Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: [ditto](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/383263/noise-problems-in-current-sensing#comment1430150_383263)